# OGF for partitions of integer r-N into even parts less than or equal to 2m (N is some integer that may depend on m).

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, generating-functions, integer-partitions

Let $a_r$ be the number of partitions of the integer r-N into even parts, the largest of which is less than or equal to 2m, where N is some integer that may depend on m. Find the ordinary generative function for the sequence {$a_0$,$a_1$,$a_2$,...,$a_r$,...}.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Even if $a_r$ is in terms of $m$, how can one answer this question without knowing how $N$ depends on $m$? How is $a_r$ defined when $r < 2m$?